# push video sources object to Jwplayer Multiple Sources object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jwplayer, jwplayer7

i want to push my returned ajax request objects to JWplayer 7 multi sources object , the returned ajax request looks like this in the console (`console.log`):

> Object {sd_src: Object, hd_src: Object}

and the sd_src & hd_src objects contains (`console.log`) :

> Object
>   file: "videofile.mp4"
>   label: "HD"
>   sd_src: Object{the same first obj}

i create empty object `dataSources = [];` to push video sources to it in the for in loop

then i create a for in loop to get object properties and push them to `dataSources` like this :

```
 for (var p in ReturnData.srcs) {
    if( ReturnData.srcs.hasOwnProperty(p) ) {
      dataSources.push( ReturnData.srcs[p] );
    }
  }
```

and the last touch i create the JWplayer 7 setup :

```
jwplayer.key="myjwplayer.key";
       var playerInstance = jwplayer("dv-watchvideo");
       var dvPlayer = playerInstance.setup({
       sources : **dataSources** ,
       image: '',
       width: 558,
       height: 360,
       type: 'mp4',
       primary: "flash",
       startparam: ReturnData.startparam,
       skin: {
         url: "thin.min.css",
           name: "thin",
              }
        });
```

> Note : the var **dataSources** between two stars

the other problem is even when i push the objects inside dataSources when i try to log the var in the console is always return object with undefined keys , but when i remove the jwplayer setup the dataSources push work !

> working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrPBO) exemple but when i use ajax to return data will not work. 
>    if my method is wrong , is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: i would try declaring your dataSources outside the jwplayer instantiation. also, you might want to try making use of the playlist[ ] wrapper. Another suggestion is to see if you can get the jwplayer setup working before you put it inside a variable. For some reason that has given me issues in the past. Also, creating a fiddle might help you get answers resolved more quickly.

Comment: @ElonZito , here is a working codepen exemple : codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrPBO exemple , but when i use to return ajax object will not work !!

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your syntax, per my suggestions in my earlier comments. Try adding your ajax sources to this pen:

http://codepen.io/simsketch/pen/KVMVKe

code excerpt:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources : dataSources 
  }],
  image: '',
  ...
```

I think your primary mistake was not adding the playlist wrapper as explained here:
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1710454-configuring-multiple-sources